# http compression and minify

Tags: jquery, http, minify

Hi getting close to finishing my coding and looking into compressions but can not find out if it advisable to do the following:

Is it best to minify scripts and html and use http compression

or

is http compression enough without minify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do both. They do different jobs -- minification actually eliminates unnecessary characters from the JavaScript code, while http compression will only squish them down.

Since http compression is done by the server automatically, it's always a good idea to leave it on. Minification is an additional step which you CAN use, but (a) isn't really helpful with small scripts and (b) should only be done as a final step before deployment anyway. In other words, you should only have to do it once anyhow.

Comment: will do both in that case. Is http compression on as defaukt? i was under the impression that you had to add something to the htaccess file?

Comment: I'm not a server guy, but as far as I know compression is not on by default.